# using My.Resources in Visual Studio (Windows Mobile)

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, windows-mobile

Hi Guys hope someone can help me before i pull all my hair out!!

In VB (Visual Studio 2010) i have written a simple coin flip routine and use the code below to display the image of the coin based on a random number 0 or 1

> coin = Rnd(1) 'random head or tail head=1 tail = 0
>           'display relevant image of coin
>           If coin = 0 Then
>               ImageCoin.Image = My.Resources.tail
>           Else
>               ImageCoin.Image = My.Resources.head
>           End If

Now i'm trying to replicate the same functionality with the windows mobile SDK but don't seem to be able to access My.Resources.  I do have two resources in the resources folder in the project head.jpg and tail.png  I've generated a random number using

> coin = rnd.Next(0, 2)

but can't seem to find a way to display the appropriate image.  Is My.Resources not available in the Windows Mobile SDK or is there a different method.

Any help really appreciated
Thanks
Damian

Answer (score 0):

This is for C#:

```
Image heads = Namespace.Properties.Resources.head;
Image tails = Namespace.Properties.Resources.tail;
```

`Namespace`, of course, is replaced with the namespace of your project.